# How to use RhinoMocks to test async WCF service call

Tags: silverlight-4.0, asynchronous, rhino-mocks

We have a Silverlight 4 app that is making the standard async call to a WCF service to get data from the database. We have an interface for this IDataService so we can mock it out. I've been reading about RhinoMocks and trying to understand how to write a test for this. I think I would need to test that the call was made to get the data (something like GetCustomers) and then that the GetCustomersCompleted method was called with the data. I've seen so many different examples today and the old way to raise an event vs the new way (and I didn't know either). Does anyone have a simple example of using RhinoMocks for this kind of test? It seems like it would be something very common if one is using TDD and RhinoMocks with Silverlight. Any examples or links would be greatly appreciated. After several days of exploring I'd be great full for any help in this area.
thanks in advance!
Bill

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling trying to write some async tests for a WPF app until I found the following blog entry:

http://blog.tatham.oddie.com.au/2009/04/09/testing-the-world-and-writing-better-quality-code-along-the-way/

I believe it should work for the Silverlight version of Rhino Mocks as well.

Comment: This helped me a bit but I'm still not quite getting it. I'm thinking there must be a fairly straight forward way to do this for SL4 which uses the Async and then Callback by raising the event.